# if-statement of frequency evaluation inside ggplot2

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, plot, count

I would like to count the occurences of my groups in the ggplot and plot them as text, but only if they fulfill a condition (e.g if equal 1, as group C in my example - plot the text).

..count.. or stat(count) does what I want, but I cant attach it to an if-statement.

So I would like to basically use group_by(group) %>% summarise(count=n())) for each group, evaluate wether it equal 1 for the given group, and than print something with geom_text().

I hope my explanation is somewhat clear - Thank you

```
df <- data.frame(
group= c("A","A","B","B","B","C",rep("D",4)),
          value= runif(sample(1:100,10,rep=TRUE)))


ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(group), y=value)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_text(aes(label = ..count..),y=0.5, stat = "count")
```

IDK how I can do that, but I would like something like this

```
#Code will not run

ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(group), y=value)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    {
     if( ???? == 1){
      geom_text( ??? )
     }
    }
```

Comment: try to use the ifelse statment inside geom_text label, something like this: geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(value <0.5, "Yes", "No"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` on `..count..`. If the count doesn't meet your condition, get it to return an empty string.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(group), y=value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(..count.. == 1, ..count.., "")), 
                y = 0.5, stat = "count")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was so close to solve it - like I tried smth like this, but I guess I missed something. Anyway, your answer worked perfectly

Comment: I actually have a follow-up question. Given I would have a third column in my data-frame (e.g "name") and would like to display its content when the if-condition is True- how would If I do that: ... ifelse(..count == 1, name, "") ... I get the error ": object 'name' not found"